# Wordpress Automatic Update to 3.9.1 breaks Permalinks

Tags: permalinks, updates

Yesterday, WordPress 3.9.1 Maintenance Release May 8, 2014 updated my version from the latest and all of the sudden, my inside pages were broke - no one could reach anything except the home page.

I went to permalinks, re-saved the custom permalinks to %postname% as they were. Unfortunately, this impacted visibility for some hours.

How can I allow this auto-updater to fix security issues, but prevent this permalink break from happening in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with some of my posts (not all). After updating my permalinks from /%category%/%post_id%/%postname%.html to /%postname%.html it was solved. Only issue that remains are the links to the posts shared on other websites. The link I shared (using the Sharexy plugin) to Facebook translated the permalink to the one with only the page so that one survived after the permalink update. But this didn't count for the link shared with LinkedIn.